# Cant access to the chrome settings

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping

I'm making an app that needs to autolog.For that, I'm using selenium to open a new tab and get the user and the password with web scrapping but I'm getting an java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: chrome when tryng to get the source code.How can I solve this? thxx

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", ".\\driver/chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get("chrome://settings/passwords?search=contra");

        try {
            URL dirURL = new URL("chrome://settings/passwords?search=contra");
            InputStream entry = dirURL.openStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entry));

            String line = "";
            String sourceCode = "";
            do {
                sourceCode += line + "\n";
                line = reader.readLine();
            } while (line != null);
            
            System.out.println(sourceCode);
            
            
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

So in the begining instead of:

```
webdriver.gecko.driver
```

You need to supply:

```
webdriver.chrome.driver
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it also launches a tab with the gecko driver,my problem is that I can't reach the HTML code with the URL

Comment: `chrome://settings/passwords?search=contra` is a Chrome browser specific url. Ideally you shouldn't be accessing through Firefox.